# Is OWASP.org showing the correct way of public key pinning for .NET?

Tags: c#, security, ssl-certificate

My question is inspired by reading about certificate and public key pinning over at [OWASP.org](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning#iOS).

Is is showing the following code to pin a public key when using `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback`:

```
public static bool PinPublicKey(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
  if (null == certificate)
    return false;

  String pk = certificate.GetPublicKeyString();
  if (pk.Equals(PUB_KEY))
    return true;

  // Bad dog
  return false;
}
```

As far as I understand the callback is a way for the developer to override the default validation built into .NET. The code above returns TRUE if the public keys match. However what if there are SSL errors (in the `sslPolicyErrors` param)? Shouldn't the callback return FALSE in this case?

I'm thinking the pinning part should be an additional check in case no  other errors have been detected. Otherwise I might be able to create a malicious certificate with a matching public key and spoof the client.

Comment: Yeah I'd expect something like `return sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None && certificate.Verify()`...